# RestTemplate how to Deserialize XML to POJO

Tags: java, xml-parsing, resttemplate

I'm making a utility in spring boot that communicates with Nexus to look at some artifacts.

Calling nexus to see the meta data of an artifact gives a response like this:

```
<org.sonatype.nexus.rest.model.ArtifactInfoResourceResponse>
  <data>
    <presentLocally>true</presentLocally>
    <repositoryId>REPO</repositoryId>
    <repositoryName>REPO</repositoryName>
    <repositoryPath>/path/to/artifact.jar</repositoryPath>
    <mimeType>application/java-archive</mimeType>
    <uploader>svc_uploader</uploader>
    <uploaded>1511914555000</uploaded>
    <lastChanged>1511914555000</lastChanged>
    <size>146847619</size>
    <sha1Hash>137773f47a013d4ab9c6d5c2c25647011ba86929</sha1Hash>
    <md5Hash>da472a41d439772ba898e7b0762b6835</md5Hash>
    <repositories>
      <org.sonatype.nexus.rest.model.RepositoryUrlResource>
        <repositoryId>REPO</repositoryId>
        <repositoryName>REPO</repositoryName>
        <path>/path/to/artifact.jar</path>
        <artifactUrl>https://nexus.internal.org/content/repositories/path/to/artifact.jar</artifactUrl>
        <canView>true</canView>
      </org.sonatype.nexus.rest.model.RepositoryUrlResource>
    </repositories>
    <canDelete>false</canDelete>
  </data>
</org.sonatype.nexus.rest.model.ArtifactInfoResourceResponse>
```

I've been trying to map this to my Pojo defined like this:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "data")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class NexusArtifactData {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "md5Hash")
    private String md5Hash;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "sha1Hash")
    private String sha1Hash;
}
```

With all the research I've been doing, and tinkering I've done with various annotations, this should work. Unfortunately, `md5Hash` and `sha1Hash` are initialized to null. This is trivial with JSON, how do I deserialize this XML to an easy to use POJO?